# How can I use Python's Requests to fake a browser visit a.k.a and generate User Agent?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, wget, user-agent

I want to get the content from [this website](http://www.ichangtou.com/#company:data_000008.html).

If I use a browser like Firefox or Chrome, I could get the real website page I want, but if I use the Python [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package (or `wget` command) to get it, it returns a totally different HTML page.

I thought the developer of the website had made some blocks for this.

How do I fake a browser visit by using Python's Requests or command *[wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)*?

Comment: Who chooses these names? There is [a well-known example of typosquatting](https://lwn.net/Articles/694830/) involving Requests ("Request" - without the "s"). See also *[What is the story behind RussianIdiot on PyPI?](https://web.archive.org/web/20200131074235/https://github.com/russianidiot?tab=repositories)*.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

Provide a [`User-Agent` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent):

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.ichangtou.com/#company:data_000008.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

FYI, here is a list of User-Agent strings for different browsers:

- [List of all Browsers](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

---

As a side note, there is a pretty useful third-party package called [fake-useragent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent) that provides a nice abstraction layer over user agents:

> fake-useragent
>
> Up to date simple useragent faker with real world database

Demo:

```
>>> from fake_useragent import UserAgent
>>> ua = UserAgent()
>>> ua.chrome
u'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'
>>> ua.random
u'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried with the headers in my requests but still could not get the real content of the page, there's a string 'Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled in order for this application to display correctly.' in the returned html page, should I add java script support in the requests? If so how would I do that?

Comment: @user1726366: You can't simply add JavaScript support - you need a JavaScript interpreter for that. The simplest approach is to use the JavaScript interpreter of a real Web browser, but you can automate that from Python using [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: @alecxe,@sputnick: I tried to capture the packets with wireshark to compare the difference from using python requests and browser, seems like the website url isn't a static one I have to wait for the page render to complete, so **Selenium** sounds the right tools for me. Thank you for your kind help. :)

Comment: Turns out some search engines filter some `UserAgent`. Anyone know why ? Could anyone provide a list of acceptable  `UserAgent`s ?

Comment: This is the top User-Agent attacking us nowadays, I wonder why ><

Comment: The link to [List of all Browsers](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) seems to be dead now.

Comment: Is this legal?  What if I develop a mobile app that uses this in the backend and some website gets high enough traffic to cause problems?

Comment: https://user-agents.top is also hosting a list of user agents. There are lists of user agents that passed captcha test

Comment: The mentioned Python library [fake_useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) is outdated for a long time and does not work on my system. The instantiation fails under whatever circumstances.

Answer (score 57):

I used [fake UserAgent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent).

Install:

```
pip install fake-useragent
```

How to use:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests
   

ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.chrome)
header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
print(header)
url = "https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/recent-submissions?filter=file&sort=^timestamp"
htmlContent = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print(htmlContent)
```

Output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; OpenBSD i386) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}
<Response [200]>
```

Additional features are available as well. Random return a only Edge or Chrome browser user agents:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent(browsers=['edge', 'chrome'])
ua.random
```

Randomly return only Linux OS user agent strings:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent(os='linux')
ua.random
```

Or randomly return user agent strings with a minimum usage percentage of 1.3% or higher:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent(min_percentage=1.3)
ua.random
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171209/discussion-between-umesh-kaushik-and-maksim-kniazev).

Comment: 404 should now be resolved.I'm the maintainer of this Python package. It also has now the ability to filter on OS and usage percentage.

Answer (score 11):

Try doing this, using Firefox as a fake [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) (moreover, it's a good startup script for web scraping with the use of cookies):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# vim:ts=4:sw=4


import cookielib, urllib2, sys

def doIt(uri):
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    page = opener.open(uri)
    page.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    print page.read()

for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    doIt(i)
```

#### Usage:

```
python script.py "http://www.ichangtou.com/#company:data_000008.html"
```

Answer (score 7):

The root of the answer is that the person asking the question needs to have a JavaScript interpreter to get what they are after. I have found I am able to get all of the information I wanted on a website in JSON before it was interpreted by JavaScript. This has saved me a ton of time in what would be parsing HTML content, hoping each webpage is in the same format.

So when you get a response from a website using Requests, really look at the *html/text* part because you might find the JavaScript's JSON in the footer ready to be parsed.

Answer (score 6):

I use [pyuser_agent](https://pypi.org/project/pyuser-agent/). This package uses get user agent.

```python
import pyuser_agent
import requests

ua = pyuser_agent.UA()

headers = {
      "User-Agent" : ua.random
}
print(headers)

uri = "https://github.com/THAVASIGTI/"
res = requests.request("GET",uri,headers=headers)
print(res)
```

#### Console output

```
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; zh-CN) AppleWebKit/533+ (KHTML, like Gecko)'}
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: I think you should disclose that you are the author of the software you are promoting here.

Comment: What do you mean by *"This package uses get user agent"* (seems incomprehensible)? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

### Answer

You need to create a header with a proper formatted [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP) string. It serves to communicate client-server.

**You can check your own user agent [Here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).**

### Example

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
```

### Third party Package [user_agent 0.1.9](https://pypi.org/project/user_agent/)

I found this module very simple to use, in one line of code it randomly generates a User agent string.

```
from user_agent import generate_user_agent, generate_navigator
from pprint import pprint

print(generate_user_agent())
# 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64)'

print(generate_user_agent(os=('mac', 'linux')))
# 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'

pprint(generate_navigator())

# {'app_code_name': 'Mozilla',
#  'app_name': 'Netscape',
#  'appversion': '5.0',
#  'name': 'firefox',
#  'os': 'linux',
#  'oscpu': 'Linux i686 on x86_64',
#  'platform': 'Linux i686 on x86_64',
#  'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0',
#  'version': '41.0'}

pprint(generate_navigator_js())

# {'appCodeName': 'Mozilla',
#  'appName': 'Netscape',
#  'appVersion': '38.0',
#  'platform': 'MacIntel',
#  'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0'}
```

Answer (score 2):

User agent is OK, but he wants to fetch a JavaScript site. We can use [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29), but it is annoying to set up and maintain, so the best way to fetch a JavaScript rendered page is the *requests_html* module. Which is a superset of the well-known Requests module. To install, use pip:

```
pip install requests-html
```

And to fetch a JavaScript rendered page, use:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://python.org/')
```

It uses puppter to render JavaScript and also it downloads [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)), but you don't have to worry about everything that is happening under the hood. You will get the end result.

Comment: ***No***, it is with "s" at the end (*Requests*). That is how [typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting) comes about. See e.g. *[Typosquatting in package repositories](https://lwn.net/Articles/694830/)*.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but I was unable to use the `UserAgent` class inside the `fake_useragent` module. I was running the code inside a [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) container.

```
import requests
import ujson
import random

response = requests.get('https://fake-useragent.herokuapp.com/browsers/0.1.11')
agents_dictionary = ujson.loads(response.text)
random_browser_number = str(random.randint(0, len(agents_dictionary['randomize'])))
random_browser = agents_dictionary['randomize'][random_browser_number]
user_agents_list = agents_dictionary['browsers'][random_browser]
user_agent = user_agents_list[random.randint(0, len(user_agents_list)-1)]
```

I targeted the endpoint used in the module. This solution still gave me a random user agent. However, there is the possibility that the data structure at the endpoint could change.

Answer (score 1):

This is how, I have been using a random user agent from a list of nearlly 1000 fake user agents

```
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
from random_user_agent.params import SoftwareName, OperatingSystem
software_names = [SoftwareName.ANDROID.value]
operating_systems = [OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.value, OperatingSystem.LINUX.value, OperatingSystem.MAC.value]   

user_agent_rotator = UserAgent(software_names=software_names, operating_systems=operating_systems, limit=1000)

# Get list of user agents.
user_agents = user_agent_rotator.get_user_agents()

user_agent_random = user_agent_rotator.get_random_user_agent()
```

**Example**

```
print(user_agent_random)
```

*Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36*

For more details visit this [**link**](https://pypi.org/project/random-user-agent/)