# Requesting web page with Python

Tags: python

Im trying to retrive a bunch of web pages using the follwing code

```
for i in range(619,333333):
print i
num=str(i)
urll='http://shironet.mako.co.il/artist?type=works&lang=1&prfid=%s' %num
r = requests.get(urll,timeout=5,headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print r.text
```

some of this web pages are exists for sure for example:
http://shironet.mako.co.il/artist?type=works&lang=1&prfid=
 but when im running the code im getting the following results:

> Blockquote
>   window.rbzns = {fiftyeightkb: 3600000, days_in_week : 1};var h9U={'L6':function(U,b){return U!=b;},'t6':function(U,b){return U|b;},'R6':function(U,b){return U>>>b;},'l2':function(U,b){return U===b;},'T7H':(function(L7H){return (function(C7H,r7H){return (function(W7H){return {v7H:W7H};})(function(B7H){var R7H,E7H=0;for(var q7H=C7H;E7HF7H;})(parseInt,Date,(function(J7H){return (''+J7H)"substring";})('_getTime2'),function(J7H,P7H){return new J7H()P7H;}),function(B7H,E7H){var O7H=parseInt(B7H"charAt",16)"toString";return O7H"charAt";});})('6ia8u0v00'),'n2':function(U,b){return U==b;},'x2':function(U,b){return U&b;},'N0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'p6':function(U,b){return U|b;},'c3':function(U,b){return Ub;},'e2':function(U,b){return U!==b;},'j0':function(U,b){return U>b;},'k7':function(U,b){return Ub;},'B7':function(U,b){return U<>b;},'O1':"getTimezoneOffset",'S3':function(U,b){return U=b;},'N7':function(U,b){return U==b;},'c7':function(U,b){return U<>>b;},'x6':function(U,b){return U&b;},'M7':function(U,b){return U<>>b;},'u0':function(U,b,D,k){return U^b^D^k;},'m6':function(U,b,D){return U|b|D;},'X7':function(U,b){return U&b;},'s7':function(U,b){return U!=b;},'E5':function(U,b){return U&b;},'q6':function(U,b){return U&b;},'M3':function(U,b){return U>=b;},'Q3':function(U,b){return U>=b;},'f2':function(U,b){return U|b;},'W2':function(U,b){return U|b;},'P0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'I9':"undefined",'i6':function(U,b){return U>b;},'k6':function(U,b){return U|b;},'j7':function(U,b){return U>>b;},'G0':function(U,b){return U>=b;},'d6':function(U,b){return U&b;},'r2':function(U,b){return U&b;},'S5':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'p2H':"Fingerprint",'Q8':"charCodeAt",'q0':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'n1':function(U,b){return U===b;},'T3':function(U,b){return U&b;},'l1':function(U,b){return U in b;},'j3':function(U,b){return U>b;},'p1':function(U,b){return U>>b;},'h7':function(U,b){return U>>b;},'D8':"-",'U2H':"function",'Q0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'v5':function(U,b){return U>>>b;},'R9':"test",'D0':function(U,b){return U&b;}};var bsig;try{(function(U,b,D){var k=h9U.T7H.v7H("543")?"temp":"amd",Q=h9U.T7H.v7H("1c")?"exports":"n";h9U.I9!==typeof module&&module[Q]?module[Q]=D():h9U.U2H===typeof define&&define[k]?define(D):b[U]=D();})(h9U.p2H,this,function(){var I=h9U.T7H.v7H("f1")?"D":"getContext",A=h9U.T7H.v7H("38")?"createElement":"Fingerprint",s=h9U.T7H.v7H("5fd")?"userAgent":"encoded",t=h9U.T7H.v7H("5b57")?"getRegularPluginsString":"ie_activex",O=h9U.T7H.v7H("d8db")?"screen_orientation":"length",B=h9U.T7H.v7H("d8")?"screen_resolution":"result",V="hasher",f=h9U.T7H.v7H("65")?null:"cookie",C="map",N=function(j){var m=h9U.T7H.v7H("cf7")?"getContext":"call";var u=h9U.T7H.v7H("cdd")?"counter_x":"each";var T,Z;T=Array.prototype.forEach;Z=Array.prototype.map;this[u]=function(U,b,D){var k="l2";var Q="hasOwnProperty";var H=h9U.T7H.v7H("a2c")?31:"e2";var y=h9U.T7H.v7H("2eb")?"p2":32768;var o="forEach";var M="k2";var h="U2";if(h9Uh)if(T&&h9UM)Uo;else if(U.length===+U.length)for(var p=0,K=U.length;h9Uy&&h9UH;p++);else for(p in U)if(UQ&&h9Uk)break;};this[C]=h9U.T7H.v7H("a41")?function(k,Q,H){var y=h9U.T7H.v7H("134")?61:"Y2";var o="n2";var M=[];if(h9Uo)return M;if(Z&&h9Uy)return kC;thisu;return M;}:8388608;"object"==typeof j?(this[V]=h9U.T7H.v7H("fa12")?"atob":j[V],this[B]=j[B],this[O]=h9U.T7H.v7H("382")?j[O]:"hasher",this.canvas=j.canvas,this[t]=h9U.T7H.v7H("ec4")?"canvas":j[t]):"function"==typeof j&&(this[V]=j);};N.prototype={get:function(){var U="murmurhash3_32_gc",b=h9U.T7H.v7H("6ce1")?"getCanvasFingerprint":"outerWidth",D="isCanvasSupported",k="getPluginsString",Q="doNotTrack",H="platform",y="cpuClass",o="openDatabase",M="addBehavior",h="body",p=h9U.T7H.v7H("86ff")?"pageXOffset":"indexedDB",K=h9U.T7H.v7H("3d31")?"hasLocalStorage":"hasLocalStorage",j="hasSessionStorage",m=h9U.T7H.v7H("5a3")?"window":"getScreenResolution",u="colorDepth",T="language",Z=[];Zh9U.k5H;Zh9U.k5H;Zh9U.k5H;this[B]&&"undefined"!==typeof thism&&Zh9U.k5H;Z[h9U.k5H]((new Date)h9U.O1);Zh9U.k5H;Zh9U.k5H;Zh9U.k5H;document[h]?Z[h9U.k5H](typeof document[h][M]):Zh9U.k5H;Z[h9U.k5H](typeof window[o]);Zh9U.k5H;Zh9U.k5H;Zh9U.k5H;Zh9U.k5H;this.canvas&&thisD&&Zh9U.k5H;return this[V]?thisV:thisU;},murmurhash3_32_gc:function(U,b){var D="F5",k="E5",Q="v5",H="a5",y=h9U.T7H.v7H("7a21")?29:"K5",o=h9U.T7H.v7H("473")?1732584193:"Y5",M="n5",h="l5",p="e5",K="H5",j="g5",m=h9U.T7H.v7H("3dff")?"::":"b5",u="d2",T="x2",Z="W2",J=h9U.T7H.v7H("8e")?19:"r2",E=h9U.T7H.v7H("4ebf")?30:"f2",L="F2",F="E2",g="v2",R="a2",a="K2",P,X,e,l,v;P=h9Ua;X=h9UR;e=h9U.T7H.v7H("1d")?"emit":b;for(v=0;h9Ug;)l=h9UF|(Uh9U.Q8&255)<<8|(Uh9U.Q8&255)<<16|(Uh9U.Q8&255)<<24,++v,l=h9UL,l=h9UE,l=h9UJ,e^=l,e=h9UZ,e=h9UT,e=(h9Uu)+27492+(h9Um);l=0;switch(P){case 3:l^=h9Uj;case 2:l^=h9UK;case 1:l^=h9U.T7H.v7H("353")?h9Up:12,l=h9U.T7H.v7H("86e")?255:h9Uh,l=h9UM,e^=h9Uo;}e^=U.length;e^=h9Uy;e=h9U.T7H.v7H("4224")?24:h9UH;e^=h9UQ;e=h9Uk;return h9UD;},hasLocalStorage:function(){var b=h9U.T7H.v7H("21a7")?"frames":"localStorage";try{return !!window[b];}catch(U){return !0;}},hasSessionStorage:function(){var b=h9U.T7H.v7H("c2")?"milliseconds":"sessionStorage";try{return !!window[b];}catch(U){return !0;}},isCanvasSupported:function(){var U=h9U.T7H.v7H("355f")?"cpuClass":documentA;return !(!U[I]||!UI);},isIE:function(){var U="r5",b=h9U.T7H.v7H("b4")?"appName":"outerHeight",D=h9U.T7H.v7H("daef")?2562383102:"f5";return h9UD?"hasOwnProperty":"description",H=h9U.T7H.v7H("451f")?"name":"s",y=h9U.T7H.v7H("22c")?"2d":this[C](k,function(U){var b=h9U.T7H.v7H("b3")?"Fingerprint":"suffixes";var D="type";return [U[D],U[b]]h9U.l9;})h9U.l9;return [k[H],k[Q],y]h9U.l9;},this)h9U.l9;},getIEPluginsString:function(){var D="split",k="ActiveXObject";return window[k]?thisC,function(b){try{return new ActiveXObject(b),b;}catch(U){return null;}})h9U.l9:"";},getScreenResolution:function(){var U=h9U.T7H.v7H("15e")?"x":"W5";return this[O]?h9UU?[screen.height,screen.width]:[screen.width,screen.height]:[screen.height,screen.width];},getCanvasFingerprint:function(){var U="toDataURL",b=documentA,D=h9U.T7H.v7H("de2")?bI:"object";D.textBaseline="top";D.font="14px 'Arial'";D.textBaseline="alphabetic";D.fillStyle="#f60";D.fillRect(125,1,62,20);D.fillStyle="#069";D.fillText("http://valve.github.io",2,15);D.fillStyle="rgba(102, 204, 0, 0.7)";D.fillText("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890",4,17);return bU;}};return N;});bsig=new Fingerprint({canvas:true})h9U.d2H;}catch(b){var z=h9U.T7H.v7H("b55e")?function(U){bsig=h9U.T7H.v7H("bce8")?U:"g";}:4;z(h9U.D8);}(function(){var x="winsocks",G="outerWidth",W="documentElement",d="document",F4=h9U.T7H.v7H("3fb")?"z7":"; path=/",L4="w5",P4=h9U.T7H.v7H("f18a")?65:"S5",J4=h9U.T7H.v7H("fd")?"date":"fromCharCode",w=h9U.T7H.v7H("2d")?"replace":"getContext",r="charAt",S="toString",U4=function(U,b){var D="G0";return h9UD;},q=function(U,b){var D="u3";var k=h9UD;return k;},i=function(b){var D="B3";var k="";var Q;var H;for(Q=7;h9UD;Q--){var y=function(){var U="J3";H=h9UU;};y();k+=HS;}return k;},d4=function(b){var D="t3";var k="";var Q;var H;var y;for(Q=0;h9UD;Q+=2){var o=function(){var U="T3";H=h9UU;};var M=function(){var U="s3";y=h9UU;};o();M();k+=HS+yS;}return k;},c4=function(U){var b="h3";var D="toUpperCase";var k="j3";var Q=0;var H=0;var y;while(h9Uk){y=Ur;H++;switch(yD){case "0":Q+=4;break;case "1":Q+=3;break;case "2":case "3":Q+=2;break;case "4":case "5":case "6":case "7":Q+=1;break;}if(h9Ub)break;}return Q;},R4=function(b){var D="toLowerCase";var k="q0";var Q="L0";var H="O0";var y="I0";var o="u0";var M="h0";var h="j0";var p="i6";var K="q6";var j="R6";var m="L6";var u="P6";var T="s6";var Z=function(){var U="m6";g=h9UU;};var J=function(){var U="t6";g=h9UU;};var E=function(){var U="j6";g=h9UU;};var L=function(U){g=U;};var F;var g,R;var a=new Array(80);var P=1732584193;var X=4023233417;var e=2562383102;var l=271733878;var v=3285377520;var I,A,s,t,O;var B;b=r4(b);var V=b.length;var f=new Array;for(g=0;h9UT;g+=4){var C=function(){var U="T6";R=h9UU;};C();fh9U.k5H;}switch(h9Uu){case 0:L(2147483648);break;case 1:J();break;case 2:Z();break;case 3:E();break;}fh9U.k5H;while(h9Um)fh9U.k5H;fh9U.k5H;fh9U.k5H;for(F=0;h9Up;F+=16){var N=function(){var U="x6";v=h9UU;};var g4=function(){var U="M0";P=h9UU;};var Q4=function(U){t=U;};var D4=function(U){s=U;};var k4=function(U){A=U;};var y4=function(){var U="d6";l=h9UU;};var M4=function(){var U="D0";e=h9UU;};var p4=function(){var U="Q0";X=h9UU;};var H4=function(U){I=U;};var l4=function(U){O=U;};var j4=function(U){a[g]=U[F+g];};for(g=0;h9Uh;g++)j4(f);for(g=16;h9UM;g++)a[g]=q(h9Uo,1);H4(P);k4(X);D4(e);Q4(l);l4(v);for(g=0;h9Uy;g++){var Z4=function(U){O=U;};var e4=function(U){A=U;};var m4=function(U){I=U;};var n4=function(){var U="V0";B=q(I,5)+(h9UU|~A&t)+O+a[g]+1518500249&4294967295;};var h4=function(U){t=U;};n4();Z4(t);h4(s);s=q(A,30);e4(I);m4(B);}for(g=20;h9UH;g++){var o4=function(U){O=U;};var t4=function(U){I=U;};var A4=function(U){t=U;};var Y4=function(){var U="P0";B=h9UU;};var u4=function(U){A=U;};Y4();o4(t);A4(s);s=q(A,30);u4(I);t4(B);}for(g=40;h9UQ;g++){var a4=function(U){t=U;};var s4=function(U){A=U;};var I4=function(U){O=U;};var K4=function(){var U="R0";B=h9UU;};var v4=function(U){I=U;};K4();I4(t);a4(s);s=q(A,30);s4(I);v4(B);}for(g=60;h9Uk;g++){var O4=function(U){A=U;};var B4=function(U){I=U;};var E4=function(U){t=U;};var V4=function(){var U="N0";B=h9UU;};var T4=function(U){O=U;};V4();T4(t);E4(s);s=q(A,30);O4(I);B4(B);}g4();p4();M4();y4();N();}var B=i(P)+i(X)+i(e)+i(l)+i(v);return BD;},f4=function(){var U="domAutomationController";var b="domAutomation";var D="webdriver";var k="spawn";var Q="emit";var H="Buffer";var y="__phantomas";var o="callPhantom";var M="_phantom";if(window[M]||window[o]||window[y]||window[H]||window[Q]||window[k]||window[D]||window[b]||window[U]){return true;}return false;},r4=function(U){var b="M6";var D="p6";var k="k6";var Q="z6";var H="w3";var y="S3";var o="C3";var M="X3";var h="c3";U=U[w](/%5Cr%5Cn/g,"%5Cn");var p="";for(var K=0;h9Uh;K++){var j=Uh9U.Q8;if(h9UM)p+=sfcc(j);else if(h9Uo&&h9Uy){p+=sfcc(h9UH);p+=sfcc(h9UQ);}else{p+=sfcc(h9Uk);p+=sfcc(h9UD);p+=sfcc(h9Ub);}}return p;};sfcc=String[J4],io="indexOf",at3="@@@",chars=[];for(var c=65;h9UP4;c++){charsh9U.k5H;}for(var c=97;h9UL4;c++){charsh9U.k5H;}for(var c=48;h9UF4;c++){charsh9U.k5H;}charsh9U.k5H;charsh9U.k5H;charsh9U.k5H;chars=charsh9U.l9;if(typeof b4=="undefined"){function b4(U){var b="t7",D="u7",k="h7",Q="j7",H="M7",y="p7",o="k7",M=[],h=0;while(h9Uo){var p=Uh9U.Q8,K=Uh9U.Q8,j=Uh9U.Q8,m=(h9Uy)+(h9UH)+(j||0),u=h9UQ,T=h9Uk,Z=isNaN(K)?64:h9UD,J=isNaN(j)?64:h9Ub;M[M.length]=charsr;M[M.length]=charsr;M[M.length]=charsr;M[M.length]=charsr;}return Mh9U.l9;};}if(typeof q4=="undefined"){function q4(U){var b="M3",D="Q3",k="D3",Q="U3",H="G7",y="N7",o="C7",M="X7",h="c7",p="J7",K="B7",j="T7",m="equals",u="chars",T="strlen",Z="s7",J={strlen:h9UZ,chars:(new RegExp("[^"+chars+"]"))h9U.R9,equals:/=/h9U.R9&&(/=[^=]/h9U.R9||/={3}/h9U.R9)};if(J[T]||J[u]||J[m])throw  new Error("Invalid base64 data");var E=[],L=0;while(h9Uj){var F=charsio,g=charsio,R=charsio,a=charsio,P=(h9UK)+(h9Up)+(h9Uh)+(h9UM),X=h9Uo,e=h9Uy?-1:h9UH,l=h9UQ?-1:h9Uk;E[E.length]=sfcc(X);if(h9UD)E[E.length]=sfcc(e);if(h9Ub)E[E.length]=sfcc(l);}return Eh9U.l9;};};if(!Array.prototype[io])Array.prototype[io]=function(U){var b="n1",D="l1",k="e1",Q="p1",H="floor",y="ceil",o="k1",M="U1",h=h9UM,p=Number(arguments[1])||0;p=h9Uo?Mathy:MathH;if(h9UQ){p+=h;}for(;h9Uk;p++){if(h9UD&&h9Ub){return p;}}return -1;};var n=[],Y=["object","function","number","string"],z4=true;if(typeof (pageYOffset)=="undefined"){var X4=function(U){var b="scrollLeft";pageYOffset=U[d][W][b];};X4(window);}if(typeof (pageXOffset)=="undefined"){var G4=function(U){var b="scrollTop";pageXOffset=U[d][W][b];};G4(window);}if(typeof (innerWidth)=="undefined"){var w4=function(U){var b="clientWidth";innerWidth=U[W][b];};w4(document);}if(typeof (innerHeight)=="undefined"){var S4=function(U){var b="clientHeight";innerHeight=U[W][b];};S4(document);}if(typeof (window[G])=="undefined"){var x4=function(U){var b="offsetWidth";window[G]=U[W][b];};x4(document);}if(typeof (outerHeight)=="undefined"){var i4=function(U){var b="offsetHeight";outerHeight=U[W][b];};i4(document);}if(typeof (screenX)=="undefined"){var N4=function(U){screenX=U.width;};N4(screen);}if(typeof (screenY)=="undefined"){var C4=function(U){screenY=U.height;};C4(screen);}n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (frames))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (length))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (pageYOffset))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (pageXOffset))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (innerWidth))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (innerHeight))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (outerWidth))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (outerHeight))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (navigator))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (navigator[h9U.Y8]))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (screen))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (document))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (Image))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (document))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (window))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (self))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (status))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (name))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (screenY))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (screenX))>-1);for(idx in n){if(!n[idx]){var W4=function(U){z4=U;};W4(false);break;}}if(!f4()&&!!z4){window[x]=function(E){var L="days_in_week",F="ctrbg",g="rbzns";function R(D,k,Q,H,y){var o="cookie",M="challdomain",h="toGMTString",p="getTime",K="setTime",j="fiftyeightkb",m=new Date(),u=k+"="+D,T=window[g][j];if(!y){mK;var Z="; expires="+mh;u=u+Z;}u=u+"; path=/";if(!H){var J=";domain="+window[g][M];u=u+J;}document[o]=u;if(Q){setTimeout(function(){var U="reload",b="location";window[b]U;},1);}}function a(k,Q){var H=0,y=U4(k+H,Q);(function(){var U="callee",b="Y1";if(y){var D=(h9U[b]((new Date)h9U.O1,123456789))S;R(b4(window[g][F]+at3+H+at3+D)[w](/=/g,"-"),"rbzid",E,false);}else{H++;y=U4(k+H,Q);setTimeout(arguments[U],0);}})();}a(window[g][F],window[g][L]);};}else{window[x]=function(){};}})(); rbzns.challdomain="shironet.mako.co.il"; rbzns.ctrbg="brb8ksuHgR0WzhLglimN5/vEOZXT8ta8pQ7CjdjaMLB1jNFR1vQ7oPtL47YLbNAdPhCdIms2PF6gVIVWak0+7+Gvj5fDVUYIaRdiXnH7HbY="; winsocks(true);

I notice that if Im enter the page from the browser then i get the result Im except for when Im running the code.

What should I do to handle this problem?

Comment: Haven't tried your code but sometimes it comes down to "looking" like a real browser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit. Some web sites will take measures to prevent automated visitors entirely, another possibility.

Comment: That looks like some minified/obfuscated JavaScript code. I guess the page you are requesting is using that to actually fetch and display the content, so that is what you are getting?

Comment: Tried it..it didnt work , thanks anyway

Comment: UnholySheep , If im first using chrome to get the page and than running my code im getting a proper html source page but if im not using chrome firstly im getting the minified/obfuscated JavaScript code