# Beautiful Soup <p> parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print out the titles of each item on [donedeal](https://www.donedeal.ie/) and copying the code from my own spider that works flawless at Over clockers and changing code accordingly:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
def donedeal(max_pages):
    for i in range(1, max_pages+1):
        page = (i - 1) * 28
        url = 'https://www.donedeal.ie/farming?sort=publishdate%20desc&start={}'.format(page) # http:/?...
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for title in soup("p", {"class": "card__body-title"}):
            x = title.text
            print(x)

donedeal(1)
```

Page numbers go like: `0, 28, 56..` so I had to make page number change accordingly at top of function.

The issue is that nothing is ever printed and I get exit code 0.
Thanks in advance.
Edit2: Im trying to scrape from "< p class="card__body-title">Angus calves< /p >".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inspecting the soup in pdb (break point before your for loop) I found:

```
(Pdb++) p soup
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n\n<html><head>\n<title>410 
Gone</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Gone</h1>\n<p>The requested 
resource<br/>/farming<br/>\nis no longer available on this server and there is 
no forwarding address.\nPlease remove all references to this resource.
</p>\n</body></html>\n
```

This probably means there is some anti-scraping measure in place! The site has detected that you're trying to scrape using python, and sent you to a page where you couldn't get any data.

In the future, I recommend using `pdb` to inspect the code, or perhaps printing out the Soup when you run into an issue! This can help clear up what happened, and show you what tags are available

EDIT:

Although I wouldn't necessarily recommend it (scraping is against donedeal's terms of service) there is a way to get around this.

If you feel like living on the wild side, you can make the `requests` module HTTP request look like it's coming from a real user, not a script. You can do this using the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

def donedeal(max_pages):
    for i in range(1, max_pages+1):
        page = (i - 1) * 28
        url = 'https://www.donedeal.ie/farming?sort=publishdate%20desc&start={}'.format(page) # http:/?...
        source_code = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        plain_text = source_code.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for title in soup("p", {"class": "card__body-title"}):
            x = title.text
            print(x)

donedeal(1)
```

All I did was tell the `requests` module to use the headers provided in `headers`. This makes the request look like it was coming from a Mac using Firefox.

I tested this and it seemed like it printed out the titles you want, no 410 error! :)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit) for more

Comment: Is there anything i can do to bypass this block?

Comment: See edit! I added some working code that gets you the results you were looking for. Please upvote and mark accepted if it helps!

Comment: See edit? I've been watching this question and you literally just copied Kade Killary's code from his answer. That's smelly bro.

Comment: I'll file a complaint because we don't need that in our community.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did something wrong! I cited the other user's answer, I just put it directly in line with the rest of @alienware13user 's original code.

Comment: Thanks a million for help! :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a different User-Agent in your request to make it seem like you're a real person, (i.e. headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} ). Once you do that your code works as intended.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def donedeal(max_pages):
    for i in range(1, max_pages+1):
        page = (i - 1) * 28
        req = Request('https://www.donedeal.ie/farming?sort=publishdate%20desc&start={}'.format(page), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        plain_text = urlopen(req).read()
        plain_text.decode('utf-8')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for title in soup("p", {"class": "card__body-title"}):
            x = title.text
            print(x)

donedeal(1)
```