# Web scraping (Google) using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I google `How old is Messi`, it should give me output: `30` but it instead answers me `None`.
I'm using Python 3.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
search=input("What do you want to ask: ")
search=search.replace(" ","+")
link="https://www.google.com/search?q="+search
print(link)
source=requests.get(link).text

soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
answer=soup.find('div',class_="Z0LcW")
print(answer.text)
```

Comment: @vadimKotov My answer is under 'div', having class "Z0LcW"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add User Agent to fake a real browser visit:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
source=requests.get(link, headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"html.parser")
```

Just tried that, it works.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27652558/1000551) for more info.

Answer (score -3):

First of all your soup.find is wrong, you have to make it like this
 `answer=soup.find('div',{'class':'Z0LcW'})`
Most likely the issue is you need something to load JS data.
You can use selenium + ChromeDriver

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

search=input("What do you want to ask: ")
search=search.replace(" ","+")
link="https://www.google.com/search?q="+search
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(2)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
answer=soup.find('div',{'class':"Z0LcW")
print(answer.text)
```

Hopefully that'll help.
P.S: Would suggest following [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: He is having different HTML from google because there is no User-Agent. Your answer is not relevant

Comment: Why is his `soup.find` *wrong*?