# Redirected URL in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to get redirected URL, but something doesn't work.

I tried two methods:

```
from urllib import request as uReq
import requests

#method 1
url_str = 'http://google.us/'
resp = req.urlopen(url_str)
print(resp.geturl())

#method 2
url_str = "http://google.us/"
resp = requests.get(url_str)
print(resp.url)
```

Both work and give result >>> https://www.google.com
However, when I try to add this URL: http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/lista-ofert/?f_listingId=351238&f=&submit=Szukaj as url_string nothing happens. When one's go to this site via browser he'll get that link: 
http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-wynajem-41m2-1850pln-janusza-kusocinskiego-centrum-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351238

It is important for me to get a link, because I need info from it.

Comment: Well, a plain request to that URL returns 200, not 30x. In other words, that page does not redirect at an HTTP level. *Maybe* the server is detecting the user agent and chooses not to redirect non-browser agents; try spoofing your user agent. If that's not it, the redirect is done via Javascript or meta tag client-side, at which point it's up to you how you want to parse and emulate that…

Comment: Any ideas, I don't feel to advanced to make it on my own. But I'd like to learn it!

Comment: Take a good hard look at that site's code to figure out what it's doing…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit.  Maybe I try with this

Answer (score -1):

With `allow_redirects=False` you can make the url to stay on the page which you want even though it was intended to redirect.

> resp = requests.get(url_str, allow_redirects=False)

You can find more such usage [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/)

Comment: It is the last resort for me.