# Scraping Amazon deals page not returning html code - python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently trying to scrape this Amazon page "https://www.amazon.com/b/?ie=UTF8&node=11552285011&ref_=sv_kstore_5" with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/b/?ie=UTF8&node=11552285011&ref_=sv_kstore_5'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print(soup.prettify)
```

However when I run it instead of getting the simple html source code I get a bunch of lines which don't make much sense to me starting like this:

```
<bound method Tag.prettify of <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="a-no-js" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo"><head><script>var aPageStart = (new Date()).getTime();</script><meta charset="utf-8"/><!--  emit CSM JS -->
<style>
[class*=scx-line-clamp-]{overflow:hidden}.scx-offscreen-truncate{position:relative;left:-1000000px}.scx-line-clamp-1{max-height:16.75px}.scx-truncate-medium.scx-line-clamp-1{max-height:20.34px}.scx-truncate-small.scx-line-clamp-1{max-height:13px}.scx-line-clamp-2{max-height:35.5px}.scx-truncate-medium.scx-line-clamp-2{max-height:41.67px}.scx-truncate-small.scx-line-clamp-2{max-height:28px}.scx-line-clamp-3{max-height:54.25px}.scx-truncate-medium.scx-line-clamp-3{max-height:63.01px}.scx-truncate-small.scx-line-clamp-3{max-height:43px}.scx-line-clamp-4{max-height:73px}.scx-truncate-medium.scx-line-clamp-4{max-height:84.34px}.scx-truncate-small.scx-line-clamp-4{max-height:58px}.scx-line-clamp-5{max-height:91.75px}.scx-truncate-medium.scx-line-clamp-5{max-height:105.68px}.scx-truncate-small.scx-line-clamp-5{max-height:73px}.scx-line-clamp-6{max-height:110.5px}.scx-truncate-medium.scx-line-clamp-6{max-height:127.01
```

And even when I scroll down, there is nothing that really resemble a structured html code with all the info I need. What am I doing wrong ? (I am a beginner so it could be anything really). Thank you very much!

Comment: This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit/27652558) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(soup.prettify)
```

intend to call `soup.prettify.__repr__()`. The output is

```
<bound method Tag.prettify of <!DOCTYPE html><html class="a-no-js" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo"><head>...
```

while you need to call the `prettify` method:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

The output:

```
<html class="a-no-js" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo">
 <head>
  <script>
   var aPageStart = (new Date()).getTime();
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <!--  emit CSM JS -->
  <style>
  ...
```