# Why are the parsed label names different?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

web_url = r'https://www.mlb.com/scores/2019-05-12'
get_web = requests.get(web_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_web,"html.parser")
score = soup.find_all('div',class_='container')
print(score)
```

I want to find [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjMDl.png).

But result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6xLj.png)

Comment: You are not sending headers so you will not get a HTML rendered for desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Send headers to API to tell it "hey I'm a desktop browser" to get identical HTML from server side:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
request = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
```

Useful links:

1. [How to use Python requests to fake a browser visit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit)
2. [Sending "User-agent" using Requests library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python)