# BeautifulSoup return ConnectionError

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

*I'm setting up a weather data, and I want weather(time, date, Temperature). I didn't found the solution.*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux 
x86_64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 
Safari/537.36"}

url = 'https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/new-york-ny/10007/daily-weather-forecast/349727'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
weather = soup.find('div', 'five-day').text

time = weather.find('h3')
data = weather.find('h4')
temp = weather.find('div', 'info')
print(time)
print(data)
print(temp)
```

*I have tried to change attribute and curly braces of weather variable name.*

```
weather = soup.find('div', {'class': 'five-day'}).text
time = soup.select_one('div.five-day h3')
```

**Output**

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "first_scraping_solve.py", line 6, in <module> page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', 
TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

*I expect the output is *Early Am July 21, 27 temperature, partly cloudy*

Comment: You have a space here "daily-weather- forecast" before forecast, try to remove it and see if it works

Comment: Still It's not working. I'm getting same error. It's just a mistake. I did fix it.

Comment: Can you include the full output of this script?

Comment: I tried to run your code, snd request.get is taking forever

Comment: it doesn't block if I use  `{"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}`

Comment: There is [accuweather API](https://developer.accuweather.com/) and it seems you can get 50 requests a day for free - so maybe you don't have to scrape it.

Comment: so I can use API instead scrape. so how can I do this?

Comment: there is link to [getting started](https://developer.accuweather.com/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I think the website is blocking the connection because of using same header within short span of time.
You can use multiple headers or use a third party package as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit)

To catch the exception use try and except block

```
 headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}


url = 'https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/new-york-ny/10007/daily-weather-forecast/349727'

try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:

    print(e)
    exit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

and slight modification in the code will get you the desired results

```
#print(soup)
weather = soup.find('div', 'five-day')
#print(weather)
time = weather.find('h3').text
data = weather.find('h4').text
temp = soup.find('div','temp').text
details=soup.find('div','details').text
print(time)
print(data)
print(temp)
print(details)
```

If you want to use weather and not soup then you need to use string slicing

```
temp = weather.find('div','temp').text[:4]
details=weather.find('div','details').text
```

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731/whats-the-point-of-the-x-requested-with-header

Comment: Can you make me understand the concept of try and except

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except

Comment: ok, why we need this headers, what does it work  and how to make this header (It's hard to remember this long code)?

Comment: @RohitDalal Making your script look like a browser.You need not remember this,save this code somewhere and reuse when ever needed.for more on http headers
`https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039. Did my answer worked for you?