# Scraping seloger.com, using headers and requests

Tags: python, request-headers

I am trying to execute the following code, but seloger certainly blocks the execution of the script.

https://github.com/edouardmulliez/scraper-seloger/blob/master/seloger_scraper.py

I am looking to integrate headers to get around the issue, as described here

[How to use Python requests to fake a browser visit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit)

however I did not succeed in getting it working. Here is my code below for the while loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

locality = []
price = []
room_nb = []
bedroom_nb = []
surface = []
acc_type = []


while (page <= max_pages):
    url = ("http://www.seloger.com/list.htm?org=advanced_search&idtt=2&idtypebien=2,1&cp=75&tri=initial&LISTING-LISTpg=" +
           str(page) + "&naturebien=1,2,4")
    page += 1
    try:
        r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    except:
        # Stop visiting pages
        break
```

Comment: Try with `HTMLSession` https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/115221/requests_html.HTMLSession

Answer (score 1):

The code is good, but it looks like **it's failing because of `datadome` bot-mitigation logic**

cf. cookies attached to a **valid request** from your Chrome browser — and that you're not providing

```
datadome=63Isub0xN.YMWvZ-eAtujfObUSi_d0GOFbk0CHJdk04QDiqYSsGvn_SD~~fs6JcVRFuL2bummFzV~YqxHiO0-L5SiiXvUAhuEIcyeSTDqQdifnf7RyrQc4q5rWtq91-;
```

In order to **temporarily bypass** it:

- go on https://seloger.com with your browser
- open `Network` developer tools
- refresh your HomePage
- `copy-as-curl` the HTML valid request
- convert to `python` with this [tool](https://www.scrapingbee.com/curl-converter/python/)

Now you will be able to request the target website — and receive OK 200 status code.

Your code will look like this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.seloger.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'cookie': 'visitId=1657611082733-168489653; _gcl_au=1.1.1398385248.1657611083; _hjid=fd384eba-6c16-4f90-9c7e-c7d4ace2ce9f; _hjSessionUser_1719103=eyJpZCI6IjYwMDdhZGUzLWU1OWMtNTcwYi04ZjI1LWY3Y2FhM2I3YjI2MiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTc2MTEwODMzNjcsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; mics_uaid=web:1056:12cd1f14-72d4-4c0a-ae93-1e85e3591fc4; uid=12cd1f14-72d4-4c0a-ae93-1e85e3591fc4; mics_vid=28049671765; ABTasty=uid=wa8jg07q9m8gza0z&fst=1657611082763&pst=-1&cst=1657611082763&ns=1&pvt=4&pvis=4&th=; _ga_P0TGS7TPQ7=GS1.1.1657611082.1.1.1657612394.0; sl-pdd_LD_UserId=a4ffa357-d994-44ef-b211-9be3bae4e28c; sl-pdd.abtest.ali-ab-test=Prod; sl-pdd.abtest.c2C-block-redesign=control; sl-pdd.abtest.contact-form-ab-test=Prod; sl-pdd.abtest.enhance-map-ab-test=Excluded; sl-pdd.abtest.lead-phone-ab-test=PageVariante; sl-pdd.abtest.multivariate-test=b; sl-pdd.abtest.slider-ab-test=Excluded; sl-pdd.abtest.street-view-ab-test=Excluded; sl-pdd.abtest.tenant-file-redesign-v2=V2-reference; atuserid=%7B%22name%22%3A%22atuserid%22%2C%22val%22%3A%22701f22cd-2a06-47c6-b632-aa089014ecfb%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22end%22%3A%222023-09-04T08%3A52%3A21.103Z%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2F%22%7D%7D; _hjSessionUser_736989=eyJpZCI6IjhjOTQ1ZTdjLWQ1MTctNTY3MC05YzI2LTNjMTkxZGJkMGYxNiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTk1MTY3NDI1NDksImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; mics_vid=28049671765; ry_ry-s3oa268o_realytics=eyJpZCI6InJ5X0IxOENEMkI0LTQ4ODYtNDg1Mi05MDdBLTEwNzg1MTQxNkRCMCIsImNpZCI6bnVsbCwiZXhwIjoxNjkxMDUyNzQxODMyLCJjcyI6MX0%3D; didomi_token=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; euconsent-v2=CPdisEAPdisEAAHABBENCbCsAP_AAH_AAAAAIAwMgAFAANAAqABcADgAIAAVAAtABkADSAIoAjABMgCeAKAAUoAsgC2AF4AMIAZgA5gCAgEGAQgAjABHACUgEuATEApAClAFaALgAZYA8gB-gEDAIKAQeAjgCOgE8ALMAYEA0AB1AD9AH_ARqAj0BL4CjwF5gNaAeYBAEEAYDoAFQALgAcABAADIAGgARQAmQBPAFAAKQAZgA5gCEAEdAJcAmABSgDLAH6AQMAgoBBwCLQEcAR0AwIB1AD_gI9AXmBAEAAAA.f_gAD_gAAAAA; realytics=1; _hjDonePolls=816466; mics_lts=1661695183442; mics_lts=1661958151059; datadome=63Isub0xN.YMWvZ-eAtujfObUSi_d0GOFbk0CHJdk04QDiqYSsGvn_SD~~fs6JcVRFuL2bummFzV~YqxHiO0-L5SiiXvUAhuEIcyeSTDqQdifnf7RyrQc4q5rWtq91-; _ga_MC53H9VE57=GS1.1.1662134615.21.0.1662134615.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.418942909.1657611083; _gid=GA1.2.787398349.1662134616; _gat_tracker_pageview=1; ry_ry-s3oa268o_so_realytics=eyJpZCI6InJ5X0IxOENEMkI0LTQ4ODYtNDg1Mi05MDdBLTEwNzg1MTQxNkRCMCIsImNpZCI6bnVsbCwib3JpZ2luIjp0cnVlLCJyZWYiOm51bGwsImNvbnQiOm51bGwsIm5zIjpmYWxzZX0%3D; cto_bundle=l_qZN182RUxOMnYxWXVjeVBNJTJCNWJyeGdyJTJCN1k3V2dxYWpBWGFNNnlWZGYzQUp4WUlMS2tTUm9wbUEwVHoxR3JIdXklMkIyR3Rnd3I5aTJZZlBVQ2ZSTkRDczZ2dTlad3hBRThUZXo2cFhMZUQ3Qjh4JTJCOGdjWm1pdGhYZnBTN2lNeW5hWWY2TFRwOExyTm5HcHdBYzhsckhhaGNNRTZTaTZLcGxPWHpybVZsRng4NTI2WGJ3cGw0MHNqeXhEalVGR1clMkJKb3MlMkY; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=0; _hjSession_736989=eyJpZCI6IjZlMTQ3YTYyLWMyOTMtNDY0OC1iOWVhLTM4NzY3NzVjOTI2OSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NjIxMzQ2MTY0MzgsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _hjCachedUserAttributes=eyJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7fSwidXNlcklkIjpudWxsfQ==',
    'sec-ch-device-memory': '8',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
    'sec-ch-ua-arch': '"arm"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list': '"Google Chrome";v="105.0.5195.52", "Not)A;Brand";v="8.0.0.0", "Chromium";v="105.0.5195.52"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-model': '""',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.seloger.com/', headers=headers)
```

NB: this [repo](https://github.com/lobstrio/seloger-listings-scraper-tutorial/blob/main/seloger-listings-scraper-tutorial.py) from https://lobstr.io/ might help too

Answer (score 0):

- The issue may be occurring due to fake useragents or scraping blockage. Try adding a useragent to your scraping scheme.

  ```
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
  url = "example.com"
  r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  ```
- If it is not the issue, I am suggesting you to [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) which starts a real chromium browser and fetches through. Most of the websites can't prohibit the session.
- If it is not working, try finding APIs or data carrying mechanisms from the XMLHttpRequests on Network tab. By API parsing you can get datas fast.