# Unable to fetch cookies from the website Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am unable to get cookies from the below code.

I tried a different scraper but no progress.

Is there anyone with an idea on how to achieve it?

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
response = session.get('https://example.com')
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
```

Any suggestions is appreciated with any method.

Thanks

Comment: Only for that site or every site?

Comment: @dariofac only for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sites, including this one apparently, don't return any cookies if it doesn't look like the request is originating from a browser.

You need to pass some headers to make it look like the request is coming from a browser -- the [User-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) is often enough to get you started.

As an example, consider this:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
print(session.cookies.get_dict())

# Impersonate Firefox
headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

response = session.get('https://nseindia.com', headers=headers)
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
# Should now give you the cookies
```

There is more discussion on setting the `User-agent` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit-a-k-a-and-generate-user-agent) post.