# Why does python requests.get() retrieve different image src compared to browsing the site

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-requests, src, lxml.html

As the title suggest: calling the `requests.get()` method gives me a different image `src` link as opposed to when browsing the site manually.

I'm trying to scrape a site for products and want to store the images but the `src` I get from the site is for a very low quality image that's blurry. I compared the `src` to the one on the site and it's different. Not sure if I need to pass it something to "force" screen size in the request?

My code below:

```
from requests import get
from lxml import html

def demo():
    params = {'page': 0}
    response = get('https://www.checkers.co.za/c-2256/All-Departments', params=params)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
    images = tree.xpath('//a[@class="product-listening-click"]/img[@src]')
    images = ['https://www.checkers.co.za' + image.attrib['src'] for image in images]
    print(images)
```

The src differences of first link in list to original image on the site

```
site src:
https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10136669EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNTA4MHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g1My9oZmYvODg1NzQ3ODYyNzM1OC5wbmd8YTM4YjE3YmMxYzJjMzI4MmIzMTQ0ZWU1MjlkYjBmNWZjZGFhYzYxYzAyZGMyNDhlNDE0MDhjYWQ0MjQxNmQ3NA

retrieved src:
https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/lqi-10136669EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wxNDkwfGltYWdlL3BuZ3xpbWFnZXMvaDY1L2gwNC85MDgxNzU4NDgyNDYyLnBuZ3w0MmY3ZmMzNzJmYTU0MGIzNDk0ZjdmOTkyODYwMGI3N2I5YWJhZDRkOTljNzViYjIxMWQ3OWU2NDVjZGZhZTdm
```

EDIT 1:

I tried adding a `User-agent` header using the `fake-useragent` package and looped through all possible ones. `src` results did not change.

EDIT 2:

seems like parsing it with `lxml.html` as opposed to `bs4` gives different output  for image's `data-original-src`. Not sure why but thank you @AmineBTG for helping notice this issue.

Note:
accessing the `data-original-src` with `lxml.html` with `//a[@class="product-listening-click"]/img/@data-original-src` instead of `'//a[@class="product-listening-click"]/img[@data-original-src]'` did the trick. Header was not required by the looks of it when testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when passing the appropriate headers and retrieving the "data-original-src" attribute rather than "src" attribute. Please see below code (slightly modified)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def demo():
    header ={
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
        "cache-control": "max-age=0",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"87\", \" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"87\"",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
        "sec-fetch-site": "none",
        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
    }

    params = {'page': 0}

    r = requests.get('https://www.checkers.co.za/c-2256/All-Departments', headers = header, params=params)
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    products = s.find_all("div", {"class":"item-product__image"})
    images = ['https://www.checkers.co.za' + prod.find("img").attrs.get("data-original-src") for prod in products]

    return images

print(demo())
```

Output:

```
['https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10136669EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNTA4MHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g1My9oZmYvODg1NzQ3ODYyNzM1OC5wbmd8YTM4YjE3YmMxYzJjMzI4MmIzMTQ0ZWU1MjlkYjBmNWZjZGFhYzYxYzAyZGMyNDhlNDE0MDhjYWQ0MjQxNmQ3NA', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10136301EAV2-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1ODA4OHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g2ZS9oMGIvOTA5NjUxNTA5MjUxMC5wbmd8ZTViYzUzY2FiOWIyNWNmYmY0OGQ0ZGY0ZmY2ZDQwMGI3Nzk4ODMwOGYzMWRhNjIxOGZmM2Y1ZTExNDgxZWZjMg', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10151456EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w4NDE0NHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2gzNC9oMjIvODg1NzgxMjU5ODgxNC5wbmd8OWMxYjE4Nzc0MjNkZTU2ZGI5ZDZmN2Q2M2FhMTdhZmM3Yjc4NDgwMzEwMjg1NmNiZTM1YWNjZjkxOTUyMzhmNQ', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10151458EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1MTc0MnxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g2MS9oYmEvODg1Nzg5Nzk5MjIyMi5wbmd8ZDFhNTlkMmJiNGY3ZDA3YjU5NjkwZGMxMjY3ZTgzMDVjYzFkMDkxNzI4NzlmN2U2MjhjZGJmYjE1NDg5ZDU2ZA', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10143000EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w0NjYyN3xpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g2MC9oZDIvODg1NzY3NDA4ODQ3OC5wbmd8ZDAzYzk5ZGFkY2Y1NjBiOTllZGJjOTVkZTUwNTg3NjBhYTM4NTk0OGFiYzk4OWRlNDQxZTdkNjQzNWM5YmU1NA', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10136298EAV2-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1NzYzNXxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g3MC9oZWEvOTA5NTI5NTY2NDE1OC5wbmd8NDVkZmY4YWU4NWY3MDliYjYyNTk4MWM1NzIyOTNlMjYwMzEwOGFiNGNiZTEzNGRhMmVkZjNiZTU0ZjNiYThiMw', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10151462EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w2MzY1MHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g4Zi9oMjcvODg1NzgxNDU2NDg5NC5wbmd8ZTE5ZmViZTdjNDNkOTVjMjZkODYwMjA4YTczNTgwNjU5ZmViMmE4OTQ4YzUwYjgwMjI0ZGJkNzJkNTI5OGU0Mg', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10241929EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w2MjMwOXxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g0NS9oY2QvODg1ODQ2ODM4NDc5OC5wbmd8YzE1MGZkOWI2MjAyOWVlNzQ2YmRkMWM2MDNhZTk3ZGFkYWY4ZWMxNzA5Njc5OTMxNzY3OWEyNzg5MzczZmM1ZA', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10165121EAV2-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w2NTUzMXxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2gyZC9oYjcvODg2NDkyODM2NjYyMi5wbmd8NzEyODllNDlmZjE1NjJmMzEyMmU4MTU4NWQ4ZjRjYmM1Nzc2NWNjM2Y2YmFmZGQ1N2Y5ZjFmOTY0ZjBkMGE1OQ', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10145817EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wyMzU0MHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2gwMy9oZDIvODg1Nzc0ODc5OTUxOC5wbmd8NGQxZjA0OWNkZTVjY2JmNTI2ZTdlOGIwZjFiMmE5MGFhYjQ2NjZhMDBiYWMyNzVhYjMxNTI4YTZjYWU3OWZhZA', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10151065EAv2-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w2MDkyNHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g2Ny9oMDEvOTI3ODc2MDE4OTk4Mi5wbmd8YWQ1N2E4Y2ZmNTQ3YzA1ZDdmODcyZDlmZTg4ZGUwZGJhOWQ3ZGNiNWI5ZmE4OWFmOTVkZDgyYjEzOTUyZjlhYg', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10126789EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wxMDYzMDh8aW1hZ2UvcG5nfGltYWdlcy9oNzcvaDAzLzg4NjA4NzYzMDg1MTAucG5nfDVhMTE1MmE5YmMxNjE0OGZmM2IwOTcxMWQzYWIyY2IxOTU2MmY1M2M2N2MzZjc5ZDE2YWFmNGFiZjdiOTI1YzY', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10241933EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w2NDQ4NXxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2gzNy9oMTkvODg1ODQwMjg4MTU2Ni5wbmd8NDA5MDRlMDZkM2U3M2JiODUwNWVmYmE5YzM3NjQ3NDkxYTMzZmI0ZjY3OWFkNDZiODU2YjQ2NTRjOTQyNjI2MQ', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10147193EAV2-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w2MDk2M3xpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g4Zi9oNTUvODk1NjcwODIyNTA1NC5wbmd8YmFkMTgzZDFkNGRiY2ViMzU4MjNhMGY0ZmM1OTgyY2U4NTY5MGZiZWI5ZTMzNjE1ZTNkY2Q1YzAwY2JhZTgyYw', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10164636EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w0MDM4NnxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2gxMS9oYWIvODg1ODA5NTU4MzI2Mi5wbmd8YTYxY2ZkNjAzOTg2NGVmNGMxODVjNmRkNTAyYmYzOWM2ZDU0MzgyYzk3YjM2YWUzOTRkMGEwOWE0NmVjMDQ0NA', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10136574EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1MzU0NXxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2hjMi9oNjEvODg1NzQzMjk4MTUzNC5wbmd8YTJmZGU0ZGVjNDU1NTIyMzU0NGM1ZTQzOTQ4OTUwNmEwN2I3MDc5MjliOWNkNmRlNTgzZDMxYjdkMmNjNTIyYw', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10604301EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1OTUxN3xpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2hiZi9oZDQvODg1OTg2MzY0NjIzOC5wbmd8MTE5ZTQ4NzJkMzhjMzczMDk0MTE4YTZhZTllMTFlYjBiMTUyY2IzNjIyMmM4NzFlODA0MTU1Yzg3ZWNkMjMyNQ', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10145422EA-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w3OTc0MHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2gxYy9oNTIvODk2MjM0ODIyMDQ0Ni5wbmd8MDc5NjY1YzY2NGE0NDFiNWRiN2NkNWZkMWJlODg5MDhlOWUyZWNhNDEzMWJiZTQ3MjM5MDYyZjgzZWYyYWM2Mg', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10136291EA-20190726-Media-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w5NjM3NnxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2hjNi9oMzUvODg1NzQzMDU1NjcwMi5wbmd8ZDQwZjEzMmU5Y2JkMDhkNGM2MGQ4ZTc1MWY0Y2Q5YTJhZWI2YmM2YmY5YjNiYWEyZjQ0YWQ5ZDgyMmE3ZWE2YQ', 'https://www.checkers.co.za/medias/10148833EAV2-checkers300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w3NTU3NnxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g1OC9oNzIvODk1NjY5NjQ2MTM0Mi5wbmd8N2YyZmMxMjA5ZjkxZjkzZWExN2E2MGE1ZTZiZjI0M2FkMDcxZTVlMzY0ZjAzOTRjMjAzNzRjYWQ5Yzk4NjZkNQ']
```

Comment: So I noticed something when comparing your version and mine. The output is different depending on whether it's parsed with `bs4` or `lxml.html`. Adding the headers to and accessing the `data-original-src` with `lxml.html` seems to have no affect and gives the wrong output. Thank you for this, I want to keep the script as light as possible so I'll dig deeper as to why the output is different

Comment: I think I was access the `data-original-src` wrong with `lxml.html`. So I changed it from `//a[@class="product-listening-click"]/img[@src]` to `//a[@class="product-listening-click"]/img/@data-original-src` and now I am getting the correct image too. I'll give you the answer tick since you helped me with the `data-original-src` thought process.

Comment: Hi, yes indeed headers has no effect, the issue was on 'data-original-src'. it is just good practice to put a headers (at least the user-agent) to avoid to be blocked when web-scraping.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. Hope to use this data with a custom Alexa grocery skill :)

Answer (score 1):

When a web browser sends an HTTP request, it includes a bunch of info about itself in the header, allowing the website to retrieve a version of itself that is best suited for display in that particular browser. When you make a request via the `requests` module, the website doesn't get any of this information, and sends a version of the site that is slightly different from what you would get in a browser.

This is why you are getting two different image sources depending on how you request the website. The browser is getting a higher-quality image because the website has enough info about the way the image is going to be used to send the best possible version of the image, while the script request gets a lower-quality image because the website sends a much smaller version of the image to reduce traffic.

Comment: is there a way maybe to fake the window size with requests maybe?

Comment: Take a look at [python's request headers](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) and [User-Agent headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit-a-k-a-and-generate-user-agent)

Comment: I tried adding a user agent with fake-useragent as recommend in the links you shared but still getting the same output. I looped through all possible lists of useragents in the library/package