# Having issue scraping the html from certain websites, must enable JS and cookies enables? Using requests and bs4 for the scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have seen similar issues with trying to scrape the html of these links:
https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/15325415/2021/69/7
and https://www.just-eat.fr/en/delivery/italian-style-pizza/paris-13e-arrondissement-centre with the issue being that the html that I request is not the URL of the webpage.
This error is a part of the html that gets pulled, this specific snippet being from the first link:

```
  <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" data-translate="enable_cook
  ies" id="cookie-alert">Please enable cookies.</div>
```

Where do I configure to enable cookies so that I can scrape the data for the site?
I am currently using bs4 version 4.9.3 and requests version 2.25.1.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `headers` in which you can apply `user-agent` to access data from website.

You can learn more about `headers` from this Stack Overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit-a-k-a-and-generate-user-agent)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/15325415/2021/69/7",headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
```

> 2nd website you are looking for where data is render using Javascript
> so `bs4` will not able to find any data but you can try from XHR using
> Network tab

Comment: You're a legend! Thank you, your solution worked great.  I will check out your idea for the second link.

Answer (score 1):

For 2nd website try to use selenium to get data from pages that render using Javascript, Review this Stack Overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68999524/cant-get-all-span-tag-inside-div-element-beautifulsoup/69003136#69003136) to learn more about that

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I will look into this.  The thread made a good distinction between parsers and web retrieval tools.