# can't get all span tag inside div element beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping this [site](https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/xGYIYbJlYhsC-Senior-Python-Developer-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python%7Csearch-v3%7Chpb) and I need to get the salary value from it as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozPGs.png)

I have tried to do the flowing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/xGYIYbJlYhsC-Senior-Python-Developer-Cairo- Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|hpb")
page = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
salaries_div = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"css-rcl8e5"})
for span in salaries_div[3].select("span"):
    print (span)
```

But I am only getting this span

```
<span class="css-wn0avc">Salary<!-- -->:</span>
```

My question is why I can't get all the span inside the div?
And what should I do to get salary value in this case?

Comment: Simply because it's rendered via JS.

Comment: How can I get them in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Beautiful Soup is just a parser that works with the content you provide it with, it has nothing to do with page retrieval or rendering.

The solution that I found in my case is to use selenium to get JS rendered page.

The working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager import driver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriver, ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/xGYIYbJlYhsC-Senior-Python-Developer-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|hpb")

page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
salaries_div = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"css-rcl8e5"})
for span in salaries_div[3].select("span"):
    print (span)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content on your page is generated by JavaScript, try [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). I think it has all the functionality you need.
Your code will then look like this:

```py
### Let's import Selenium!
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox,FirefoxOptions
### At first, we need to say Selenium it should not show graphical window, so we will use Firefox in headless mode.
### We do so by creating instance of FirefoxOptions and setting its attribute 'headless' to True
opt=FirefoxOptions()
opt.headless=True
### Now, we create the actual Firefox instance and we pass it our FirefoxOptions as keyword argument 'options'
ffx=Firefox(options=opt)
### We visit your website with ffx.get()
ffx.get("https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/xGYIYbJlYhsC-Senior-Python-Developer-Cairo- Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|hpb")
### Let's now search for your spans with ffx.find_elements_by_css_selector()
elems=ffx.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.css-rcl8e5:nth-child(5)>span")
### And print the elements
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

This (at least at my case) outputs:

```html
<span class="css-wn0avc">Salary<!-- -->:</span>
<span class="css-47jx3m"><span class="css-4xky9y">Confidential</span></span>
```

To access the second element, use `elems[-1]`, and `elems[-1].get_attribute('outerHTML')` to get its html source.

But do not forget to install Selenium with

```
pip install selenium
```

And you should have Firefox with [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/) installed.

Comment: Thank you, try to use  [webdriver_manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager)
so you don't need to have a geckodriver