# BeautifulSoup Function Returning None with Span

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In this html

```
<div class="css-rcl8e5">
 <span class="css-wn0avc">
   Salary
   :
 </span>
  <span class="css-47jx3m">
    <span class="css-4xky9y">***2000 to 3000 EGP Per Month***</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the salary value using find()

```
for link in links:
    result = requests.get(link)
    src = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    salaries = soup.find("span", {"class":"css-4xky9y"})
    print(salaries)
    salary.append(salaries)
```

It returns none. I tried find_all() but it returns an empty list.
However, if I change the class to another one it works just fine. Any idea why that is and what can I do to solve this issue other than using selenium?

Comment: I tried your code with your html sample and it works... so what about your requests? try to pass a user-agent parameter

Comment: headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

Comment: The real HTML must be different than what you posted.

Comment: other than selenium i saw requests_html, haven't tried yet but looks very cool

Comment: Does the website use javascript to dynamically alter the page content?   `requests` doesn't do javascript.

Comment: Could you post what is the URL ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't get all span tag inside div element beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68999524/cant-get-all-span-tag-inside-div-element-beautifulsoup) - Think you should give selenium a chance :)

Comment: share me `website link` then I will help you