# HTML problem with tags and classes in a simple and little scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new and am trying to get BeautifulSoup to work. I have Html problems with recovering classes and tags. I get closer, but there is something I'm wrong. I insert wrong tags and classes to scrape the **title**, **time**, **link**, and **text** of a news item.

I would like to scrape all those titles in the vertical list, then scrape the date, title, link, and content.
[image]

Can you help me with the right html class and tagging please?

I'm not getting any errors, but the python console stays empty

```
>>>
```

Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
site = requests.get('url')
beautify = BeautifulSoup(site.content,'html5lib')
    
news = beautify.find_all('div', {'class','$00'})
arti = []
    
for each in news:
  time = each.find('span', {'class','hh serif'}).text
  title = each.find('span', {'class','title'}).text
  link = each.a.get('href')
  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')
  content = soup.find('div', class_ = "read__content").text.strip()
    
  print(" ")   
  print(time)
  print(title)
  print(link)
  print(" ") 
  print(content)
  print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution you can give it a try,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# mock browser request
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}
site = requests.get('https://www.tuttomercatoweb.com/atalanta/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')

news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

for each in news:
    for div in each.find_all("div"):
        print("-- Time ", div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text)
        print("-- Href ", div.find("a")['href'])
        print("-- Text ", " ".join([span.text for span in div.select("a > span")]))
```

---

```
-- Time  11:36
-- Href  https://www.tuttomercatoweb.com/atalanta/?action=read&idtmw=1661241
-- Text  focus Serie A, punti nel 2022: Juve prima, ma un solo punto in più rispetto a Milan e Napoli
------------------------------
-- Time  11:24
-- Href  https://www.tuttomercatoweb.com/atalanta/?action=read&idtmw=1661233
-- Text  focus Serie A, chi più in forma? Le ultime 5 gare: Sassuolo e Juve in vetta, crisi Venezia
------------------------------
-- Time  11:15
-- Href  https://www.tuttomercatoweb.com/atalanta/?action=read&idtmw=1661229
-- Text  Le pagelle di Cissé: come nelle migliori favole. Dalla seconda categoria al gol in serie A
------------------------------
...
...
```

EDIT:

Why headers are required here ?
[How to use Python requests to fake a browser visit a.k.a and generate User Agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27652543/4985099)

Comment: What is headers for? Can I do without it? Can I not use it? However, you forgot to scrape the text (content) of the news as well. I wrote it in the question. Thank you

Comment: You need the headers, otherwise you won't get the source HTML.

Comment: @sushanth Thanks for the edit reply and the header link. Can you change your answer by including the scraping of the text (content) of the news? In the question I wrote it, maybe you forgot :) Thank you :)

Comment: It's not that he forgot. In your code you're not even attempting the get the content of the pages. Actually, your question contains multiple questions, which means it needs more focus, otherwise it should be closed unless edited.

Comment: @sushanth Before I vote and accept your answer as a solution, can I please ask if you can remove the link for privacy reasons? Maybe replace the link with the word link or url (both in your code and in the output). The important thing, even for future users, is the beautiful soup code base. Thank you

Comment: @Jas_99, privacy reasons? It's a public site, with no personal data/information. also, you have the link/site displayed in your original post, so not sure eliminating it from the solution would really do to protect the privacy.

Comment: @chitown88 Everyone has their reasons. Removing the link I would be happy. The important thing is that the example of how to scrap with Beautiful Soup remains. Then you know, classes and tags change over time, so it's not that they are very important for the purpose of an example.

Comment: @Jas_99 I don't get it either. Are you afraid that the admin of the site is going to chase you for scraping it? It's a public domain, like millions of others. And if the classes change, then you change your scraper. Having said that's, that unusual request since you use the full domain name across your post. If the answer is helpful, accept it.

Comment: @baduker are you the lawyer of the user who answered me? :) or are you the same person? always answer for her. I just politely asked can you remove the link and replace it with url or link. you are psychoanalyzing about the reason for my request. as i said i will vote and accept the answer, but first i would like to ask the user who replied if he can remove the link please :)

Comment: @sushanth I am waiting for a response from the user :) With the utmost politeness, respect and esteem I ask you if you can remove please the link from your response and from your output, replacing it with the word "url" or "link". Most important of your answer is the code to scrape with Beautiful Soup. The link name is just something additional. I would like to understand only if you are kind enough to be able to fulfill my request :) After that, after hearing from you, I will vote on the answer and accept. Thank you. A greeting with respect and esteem :)

Comment: @sushanth I voted and accepted your answer :) For security reasons, can you remove the links from the code and output please? Maybe replace the link with the word "url" or "link". Thanks and sorry. I await your modification