# Beautiful soup took too long to get data, ps never got data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the code, it took too long to get the data, plus never retrieved the data.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print("started")
url="https://www.analog.com/en/products.html#"

def get_data(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    return soup

def parse(soup):
    datas=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-row row"})
    print(len(datas))
    return 

print("started")
soup=get_data(url)
print("got data")
parse(soup)
```

Comment: even by removing the functions, this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a User-Agent to you request header, just add

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
```

at the top of your file and then add the "headers" parameter to your request, as follows

```
r=requests.get(url,headers=header)
```

You can read more at this question: [How to use Python requests to fake a browser visit a.k.a and generate User Agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit-a-k-a-and-generate-user-agent)